# CORS Headers are not working with Icecast, despite sending the necessary headers

Tags: javascript, cors, icecast

This issue could be specifically related to Icecast, but I think it's more related to me not understanding how to solve this problem.

I'm running an Icecast server and I want to connect to it via Javascript client that is not on the same host.

It doesn't work. I get the following in the client every time.

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com:8000/live. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).**

In the Icecast config, I have this.

```
<http-headers>
    <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
    <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET POST PUT DELETE" />
</http-headers>
```

If I hit icecast with curl, here are the headers coming back.

```
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET POST PUT DELETE
```

If I take out the Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Allow-Methods, it still doesn't work.

I feel like it should just work with the Access-Control-Allow-Orgin: *.

I've read the other answers on Stackoverflow and read numerous articles about CORS, but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Looking at Devtools Network for the CORS Failure. I get this. The OPTIONS /live undefined seems like a problem.

```
OPTIONS /live undefined
Host: radio.example.com:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: icy-metadata
Referer: http://radio.example.com/
Origin: http://radio.example.com
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-GPC: 1
```

The Icecast server works just fine if I access via wget or curl or something that doesn't care about CORS. The browser seems to be expecting something that I'm not currently providing it to satisfy its CORS needs.

Comment: To figure out specifically what the problem is, open browser developer tools, select the network tab, click the request that failed and look there.

Comment: @James I updated the question with the results from the network tab.

Comment: I mean you just diagnosed the problem—your CORS methods doesn’t include OPTIONS—so I know what I’d try first since I don’t know the defaults (or what icecast is).

Comment: The request you are doing is triggering a CORS preflight by the browser.  It must not be a [simple request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests).  Either take steps to make it into a simple request, or add functionality to serve a response to the preflight (OPTIONS) request that includes the correct cors headers.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue is. It was the comment by James that sent me down the correct path. The version of Icecast that I'm running (2.4.5 - the current stable version) doesn't support CORS correctly.

I'm triggering an OPTIONS call to Icecast, but this version of Icecast doesn't support OPTIONS. According to the changelog, the beta version 2.5 does support this.

From Icecast, the protocol updates include:

- Full OPTIONS, POST, and DELETE support
- Improved CORS support

So for now, unless I want to run a beta in production, I'll have to make things work without as many fancy features in the client application I'm building that uses Icecast.

Thank you for the comments, they helped me get to the bottom of this. It was bugging me because it felt like I was doing everything correctly. Diagnosing via the Networking tab in the devtools was critical, and then that lead to the OPTIONS issue.

https://icecast.org/news/icecast-release-2_5-beta3/

Comment: `I'm triggering an OPTIONS call to Icecast` how? I've never triggered CORS pre-flight with icecast, and I've been using it for many years. Perhaps your request is the issue

Comment: Yeah, normally you won't need an OPTIONS request.  Show us what you're doing client-side.